# How to do an XSL:for-each in reverse order

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am looking to reverse in XSL/FO a for-each loop.

for instance the xml

```
<data>
  <record id="1"/>
  <record id="2"/>
  <record id="3"/>
  <record id="4"/>
  <record id="5"/>
  <record id="6"/>
</data>
```

with the xsl

```
<xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*/record">
   <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am looking for the output 654321 and not 123456

how is this possible?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [xsl:sort](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp) not for ordering by `@id` but for ordering by `position()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/data">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*/record">
        <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks specially as it's to right to left an fo:flow for arabic documents using 0.23 of FOP (customised and unable to be updated)

Comment: Correct answer. Although for this case there is no need for `descendant-or-self::*/record`. It could be just `record`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Alexander is right - forgot the data-type though:

```
<xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*/record">
   <xsl:sort select="@id" order="descending" data-type="number" />
   <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

(without that, you'll run into sorting problems with numbers over 9)

Answer (score 3):

[xsl:sort](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp) is your friend ;

```
<xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*/record">
   <xsl:sort select="@id" order="descending" />
   <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```