# How do I combine elements in a comma separated list with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following code, if Destination is not present, neither Terminal or Attention should be displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="Request.xsl" />
    <xsl:template name="Params">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Params/Destinations"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="Params">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($Destinations) &gt; 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="$Destinations"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="Desinations">
        <xsl:for-each select="/Params/Destination1/text() |
                          /Params/Destination2/text() |
                          /Params/Destination3/text() |
                          /Params/Destination4/text() |
                          /Params/Destination5/text()">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="name(.) = 'Destination1'">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/Params/Terminal1"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/Params/Attention1"/>
            </xsl:if>
                <!-- This xsl:if is repeated 5 more times with Destination2, Destination3, etc. --> 
            <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="Destination1">
        <!-- Covered in the Destinations template -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Terminal1">
        <xsl:if test="(. != '')">
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Attention1">
        <xsl:if test="(. != '')">
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to be able to get a result like so:

> Destination1-Terminal1, Destination2-Terminal2, Destination3-Terminal3-Attention3

I am getting the following result:

> Destination3, Destination1, Destination2-Terminal2-Terminal3-Attention3

As you can see, the Destinations are out of order, Terminal1 is missing and all other Terminal and Attention elements are attached to Destination2.

I am not quite sure how to combine the Destination-Terminal-Attention elements together and have the comma come after the last element in that set. For example, if Attention does not have a value I would like the comma to come after the Terminal and if neither Terminal or Attention have values then the comma should come after Destination.

Added the XML source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:include href="../base/Formatting.xsl" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>TO/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="Destinations"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Params"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Destinations" />

    <xsl:template name="Params"/>

    <xsl:template match="Params">
        <xsl:call-template name="Params"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit: I made a change to the Params template by just calling Destinations. Now none of the terminal or attention fields show up, so maybe it's a step backwards.**

Comment: Could you post an example of the input? Also indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: It's XSLT 1.0. I'm new to XSLT so I'm not sure exactly what you mean by input example. It comes through a form, where each destination, terminal, attention is a field. Destination is a 4 character length alphanumeric value (ex 1UPD). Terminal is a 3 character length alphanumeric value (ex US4) and Attention is 14 character length alphanumeric value. If that's not what you're looking for let me know. Thanks!

Comment: The input to XSLT is an XML document. We need to see it (or preferably, a minimized, but still complete example of it) in order to try and reproduce your issue. While I am at it: minimizing your XSLT code to only what's necessary to reproduce the problem **and** making it complete would also be helpful.

Comment: A few comments on your code. (a) In the name="Params" template the choose/test is unnecessary, because xsl:value-of outputs nothing if the string-length is empty. (b) The "Params" and "Destinations" templates are identical: why have two identical named templates? But your basic problem is that the union operator sorts nodes into document order.

Comment: For what it's worth, having elements named `DestinationCode1`, `DestinationCode2` etc is really bad XML design. It makes it much harder to work with using XPath or XSLT. If you have any control over that, I strongly recommend using `<DestinationCode someField="1">` etc. Your `xsl:for-each` select for example would immediately drop to `/Params/DestinationCode/text()`.

Comment: @Robert That's a stylesheet, not the input.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I modified it and included the only other file I could think of. Unless you are referring to one of the imports?

Answer (score 0):

In XPath, `|` is really a set-union operation and does not guarantee any particular ordering of the results. You can ensure a document-order scan by adding an explicit `<xsl:sort>` to your for-each loop. [How to do an XSL:for-each in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882519/how-to-do-an-xslfor-each-in-reverse-order) shows how to scan backward through the result set; changing "descending" to "ascending" should do what you want.

Or you can get rid of the `xsl:for-each` and replace it with an `xsl:apply-templates`, moving the body of the for-each into a suitable template. The apply operation [processes the selected nodes in document order unless overridden by an `<xsl:sort>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Applying-Template-Rules).

Generally, if you think you need `xsl:for-each` you should probably be looking at `xsl:apply-templates` instead (possibly with a `mode`), unless you specifically want detailed control over the order of the results. XSLT is a nonprocedural language, and works best if you use it that way -- "process these" rather than "loop over these".

Comment: The information about "//" is incorrect. All path expressions (and union expressions) deliver results in document order, and this applies both to apply-templates and for-each. Also, the reasons for the spec are not "historic": the WG that defined the rules had a completely free hand, and they chose this design for technical reasons.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Correct me if I'm wrong, but strictly speaking, I believe there's exceptions to that rule: preceding-sibling::*, preceding::*, ancestor::* and ancestor-or-self::* return nodes in reverse order, i.e. preceding-sibling::*[1] will return the immediately preceding-sibling, not the first sibling in document order. (preceding-sibling::*)[1] would return the first as per document order, however.

Comment: @MichaelKay: I'll scratch that paragraph pending sanity-check; I've been out of XSLT implementation for two years... but I have never heard a credible defense of the additional complexity of //, and would appreciate a pointer to one.

Comment: @Flynn1179 numeric predicates on reverse axes count nodes in reverse document order _for the purposes of filtering that specific location step_, true, but that doesn't change the fact that `for-each` and `apply-templates` _deliver_ the final results of processing the selected node set in document order unless you specify `xsl:sort`.

Comment: @Keshlam: I didn't claim that I like the design of //, I just queried your statement that it was constrained by history. They wanted //@x to work even though attributes aren't on the descendant axis; they wanted //p[1] to select every paragraph that's the first child of its parent, and the /descendant-or-self::node()/ mechanism is how they achieved it. With the benefit hindsight, I personally think making it mean /descendant would have been a better design.

Comment: I've never seen anyone attempt either of those with those expectations, so I'm wondering where they thought the requirement came from. And while I don't object to having an operator which would support those options, calling it // and *not* having a shorthand for descendant was guaranteed to cause confusion. Yeah, 20:20 hindsight... "Beware of premature optimization; you'll optimize the wrong thing."

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out using some of the advice keshlam provided. In my case I did not have access to the XML input that another user was asking about. I think it's generated programmatically in the application. My solution may be an abomination for XSLT but given my restrictions it works.

I modified the xsl:variable Destinations slightly:

```
<xsl:variable name="Destinations">
    <xsl:for-each select="/StatelinkQuery/Arguments/Destination1 |
                          /StatelinkQuery/Arguments/Destination2 |
                          /StatelinkQuery/Arguments/Destination3 |
                          /StatelinkQuery/Arguments/Destination4 |
                          /StatelinkQuery/Arguments/Destination5">
        <xsl:sort select="name()" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

The template for each Destination was changed to this:

```
<xsl:template match="Destination1">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/StatelinkQuery/Arguments/Terminal1"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/StatelinkQuery/Arguments/Attention1"/>
</xsl:template>
```