# XSLT to read xml in reverse order using for-each

Tags: xslt-1.0

I've below xml and would like to read it reverse order using for-each in xslt 1.0.

Input:

```
<Tokens>
    <TokenNo>370021031939737</TokenNo>
    <TokenNo>370021031939717</TokenNo>
    <TokenNo>370021031939745</TokenNo>
    <TokenNo>370021031939726</TokenNo>
</Tokens>
```

I want to read 370021031939726,370021031939745,370021031939717,370021031939737 using for-each. Can someone help.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do an XSL:for-each in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882519/how-to-do-an-xslfor-each-in-reverse-order)

Comment: I do not have sort order to use that

Comment: The linked article will reverse order based on the position of the elements which seems like what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you dkackman